# How to substitute ID with value controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, id

I have this Apex page which starts a flow which I would like to give an dynamic Id from my controller how would I write the syntax see my page:

```
<apex:page controller="NavigateToContactController">
    <flow:interview name="LerarenCommunity_Licentie_Verlenging" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/....ID....')}">
        <apex:param name="varProfielId" value="{!getLoggedInUserContact}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

I want to replace ID with {!getLoggedInUserContact} I tried:

```
"{!URLFOR(\'/{!getLoggedInUserContact}\')}"
```

But I get a Syntax error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution: finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/{!LoggedInUserContact}')}"

Comment: That shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Adrian Actually it does and is working fine, but thanks anyway

Comment: It shouldn't work; if it *does* work, it's a **bug**. Use Adrian's code instead.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for helping I tried the solution of Adrinn but as stated above I get the error: URL No Longer Exists.

Comment: Did you ever try using the more standard `$Action` global variable?

Comment: @Adrian Yes I did

Answer (score 4):

Don't merge within a merge.

```
{!URLFOR(\'/{!getLoggedInUserContact}\')}
            ^^       redundant      ^
^^    you are already within a merge    ^
```

Also, unless you named some method `getGetLoggedInUserContact`, you should remove `get` from the property name.

Also, you need a concatenation operator (`&`).

Also, you don't need to use `URLFOR` if you are constructing a literal url.

Putting it all together:

```
finishLocation="{!'/' & loggedInUserContact}"
```

---

**It would be better to use the more standardized [`$Action`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm) global variable**:

```
finishLocation="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.View, loggedInUserContact)}"
```

Comment: I do have a method named getloggedInUserContact. I tried your solution but get : Unknown property 'NavigateToContactController.getLoggedInUserContact'

Comment: If you get that error, you didn't try what I recommended. If you have a method named `getSomeProperty`, then you have a method named `someProperty`. That's why you would **change it in your markup to reference `loggedInUserContact`**. You would only reference a property named `getSomeProperty` if you had a method named `get`**`Get`**`SomeProperty`.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. But still: <apex:param name="varProfielId" value="{!LoggedInUserContact}"/> with a static finish location works. When I change the static part for "{!URLFOR('/' & loggedInUserContact)}" I get the error: URL No Longer Exists

Comment: Thanks for your help but I managed to figure it out